# Can I stack my columns or should they be inline spans?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I've had these 4 columns in place on my website for a while now. They're all set up to be in boxes of the same height and all fall in line. I'm now looking at making the site responsive and noticed these columns just overlap on smaller devices.

I want these columns to be flexible in that if it's a phone device for example it switches to 2 rows of 2 columns or 4 rows of 1 column.

I tried this using a media query and making the `.keypoints .column {` display as `block` instead of `inline-block`. However this still kept the columns in one line.

Is this simply a case of me needing to remove the columns completely and turn them into inline/block element spans depending on the screen size or can this still be done utilising my current column method?

http://jsfiddle.net/ycwtb01m/

**HTML**

```
<div class="keypoints">
    <div class="column">COLUMN1</div>
    <div class="column">COLUMN2</div>
    <div class="column">COLUMN3</div>
    <div class="column">COLUMN4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.keypoints {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1%; /* Saf3, Chrome*/
    -moz-column-count: 4;   
    -moz-column-gap: 1%; /* FF3.5+ */
    column-count: 4;        
    column-gap: 1%; /* Opera 11+*/
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 67%;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.keypoints .column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5%;
    font-family: "Swisz", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: rgb(198, 40, 22) 0px 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: you should override the width of your columns at different breakpoints, for example at 450px, make all columms 49% wide, that should force two columns next to one another and push the other two under - you should also keep these elements as `inline-block`

Comment: Check this out, this might help with responsive columns: http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm assuming you mean something along the lines of this: http://jsfiddle.net/ycwtb01m/2/
I'm still finding they stay in line on the new width. I know it will be something daft that I'm missing here.